# How to add the material from my object in unity3d to blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, objects

I added my object to blender from unity3d.

Then added shader editor and then clicked on node wrangler and then went to the folder of my air plane material there is one file .mat there i clicked on it and added it but it didn;t add the color and everything like it looks like in unity 3d.

[image: plane in blender]

the plane in unity with the plane textures:

[image: plane in unity]

How can I add the textures so it will look like the same in blender?

I follow this tutorial and in minute 1:40-1:45 he is adding materials and the object in the blender get with colors. I tried to add my plane material but it didn't change anything so I think I should add the textures somehow.

Comment: Since you haven't actually included a link to the tutorial we have no idea what he's doing! However there are several YT tutorials showing how to export materials from Unity for use in Blender. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-voE4FrU0Ms) is just one that appeared in a quick Google search.

Comment: @JohnEason good but it's not explain how to export and import the textures from unity to blender in my case the textures are 3 files of 2d type of textures.  just dragging them into blender from unity does nothing.  I tried to minimize both unity and blender and drag the textures from the unity editor assets folder or the package to the blender model i imported and it does nothing.

Comment: You still haven't provided a link to the tutorial you were following, but if it's the same one that you linked to in your other question the texture files that he points Node Wrangler at are already in the jpg and png file format that Blender understands. You can't expect it to understand files from other software so naturally it won't work. I assumed that the link I posted included instructions on exporting textures but it seems that it doesn't. Since this Q&A site is just for problems using Blender, not external software I'm afraid you're going to have to look elsewhere for answers.